# JQuery progress bar stop animate when open another tab

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a function to animate progress bar during data processing inside the div. The progress bar div is in dataprocess.php(parent page) and the process is done inside iframe that call page generate.php. My progress bar function in dataprocess.php is like below:-

```
function progressBar(percent, element)
{
    var progressBarWidth = percent * ($(element).width()) / 100;
    progressBarWidth = progressBarWidth-10;
    $(element).find('div').animate({ width: progressBarWidth }, 5).html(percent + "%&nbsp;");
}
```

The div in dataprocess.php page:-
    <div id="progressBar" class="default"><div></div></div>

In while loop inside the generate.php(iframe) I call PHP function like below to make the progress bar in parent animate:-

```
function progress($percent)
{
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
          parent.progressBar('.$percent.', "#progressBar");
          </script>';
}
```

The progress bar is working fine but the problem is when I have more than 1 tab in my browser. Now I make data processing in tab 1, this process will take about 10-15 minutes. Let say now the progress bar is 25% than I decide to go to another tab that means the tab 1 is maybe I can say in Idle state. After some time, I click back to tab 1. I can see that the percent show 100% but the progress bar continue animate from 25% until 100%. The process is already done but the progress bar stop animate if I turn to another tab and only working back when I go back to the data processing tab.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in that case, try using css3 transitions instead of js animations.

replace:

```
$(element).find('div').animate({ width: progressBarWidth }, 5).html(percent + "%&nbsp;");
```

with:

```
$(element).find('div').width(progressBarWidth).html(percent + "%&nbsp;");
```

and add a css for that `div` that you want to animate, let's call it for example `myDiv`:

```
#myDiv{transition:width .1s ease;-moz-transition:width .1s ease;-webkit-transition:width .1s ease;-ms-transition:width .1s ease;}
```

hope that helps